# I need to generate a new activity based on the selection of Spinner,Textview and a button (Submit) on the previous activity

Tags: android, android-intent

Inputs: Spinner(dropdown), Textview(Name)
User clicks on button Submit and accordingly it should navigate to particular page.

Spinner has the specific activity while Textview has userinput which would be visible on the next activity

Comment: what you have done so far.

Comment: Spinners have a selection event listener... Are you having issues defining that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Extras to an intent you use to create new activity with `intent.putExtra()`.
In a new activity you should get extras of that intent.
call `intent.getIntExtra()` etc.
You can get intent that was used to create an activity using getIntent().